# Cakephp2 - Creating Form from loop

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have translates table with example data:

[image]

So, this table holds records, which will represent custom translation texts.

Now i want to build a form to edit all of those rows in one page / form.

This is controlle code:

```
public function translate()  {
    $this->loadModel('Translate');
    $data = $this->Translate->find('all');
    $this->set('data', $data);

    pr ($this->request->data);

    if ($this->request->is('post','put')) {

        if ($this->Translate->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Recipe Saved!');
            return $this->redirect($this->referer());
        }
    }
}
```

And view - please note, that i have used loop for creating inputs, not sure if cakephp has better way to do this.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Translate'); ?>
<?php
foreach ($data as $d) {
    echo $this->Form->input('text', array('label' => 'Link strony', 'type' => 'text','value'=>$d['Translate']['text']));
    echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $d['Translate']['id']));
}
?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(array('class' => 'btn btn-success floatRight', 'label' => 'Zapisz')); ?>
```

For now, this code works, but not as i expect. `$this->request->data` shows only last input, ignoring other ones. Attached, you see debug of $this->request->data. Only last item is edited. All i want is to have ability to edit selected input and save. Thanks for help.

[image]

Comment: Try to specify the name : ` echo $this->Form->input('text', array('label' => 'Link strony', 'type' => 'text','value'=>$d['Translate']['text'],'name'=>'translate[]'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Looks like you're saving multiple rows in a single form. In that case,
>   you need to change your approach a bit.
>
> 1. Use **proper indices** in the Form helper.
> 2. Use **saveAll()** instead of save() to save multiple data.

Changes to the View file:

```
    <?php
       foreach ($data as $k => $d) {
           echo $this->Form->input('Translate.'.$k.'.text', array(
            'label' => 'Link strony', 
            'type'  => 'text',
            'value' =>$d['Translate']['text']
           ));

           echo $this->Form->input('Translate.'.$k.'.id', array(
               'type'  => 'hidden', 
               'value' => $d['Translate']['id']
           ));
      }
    ?>
```

And then, in your controller:

```
if ($this->request->is('post','put')) {

       $this->Translate->saveAll($this->request->data['Translate']);

      /* Other code */
}
```

Comment: HI,Thanks - now this>request->data has all items on submit hit, but data is not saving into db :(

Comment: You could try $this->request->data['Translate'] instead of $this->request->data. That should work.

Comment: hint ```>input(sprintf('Translate.%s.text', $k), .. ```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the name as array (translate[]) :

```
echo $this->Form->input('text', array('label' => 'Link strony', 'type' => 'text','value'=>$d['Translate']['text'],'name'=>'translate[]'));
```